# Slug solution for a DDD entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, domain-driven-design

I consider a slug property not being a part of my domain model. It's just a nice convenience for the view layer.

But still: I don't want to calculate it each time I retrieve it to the view.

So I decide to only define a private property with a getter on entities which eventually will be retrieved via an URL - through a `Sluggable` contract. The `constructor` doesn't touch it all. I delegate the slug's creation to an Infrastructure Service. The ORM deals with entities using reflections, so my solution kind of looks like how Doctrine would touch those.

I register the event lifecycle listener as a Symfony service.

```
<?php

namespace App\Common\Domain\Model;

interface Sluggable
{
    public function slug();
}
```

```
<?php

namespace IMS\Registry\Domain\Model\Manufacturer;

use App\Common\Domain\Model\Sluggable;

class Manufacturer implements Sluggable
{
    private ManufacturerId $id;

    private ManufacturerName $name;

    private string $slug;

    public function __construct(ManufacturerId $anId, ManufacturerName $aName)
    {
        $this->id = $anId;
        $this->name = $aName;
    }

    public function name(): ManufacturerName
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function slug(): string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
    
    // other methods
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Common\Infrastructure\Domain\Model;

use App\Common\Domain\Model\Sluggable;
use Cocur\Slugify\SlugifyInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class NameSlugger
{
    public function __construct(private readonly SlugifyInterface $slugger)
    {
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $this->preSlugged($args);
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $this->preSlugged($args);
    }

    private function preSlugged(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if (!$entity instanceof Sluggable) {
            return;
        }

        $reflection = $args->getObjectManager()->getClassMetadata($entity::class)->getReflectionClass();
        if (!$reflection->hasProperty('slug')) {
            throw new \ReflectionException();
        }

        $reflectionProperty = $reflection->getProperty('slug');
        if (!$reflectionProperty->hasType()) {
            throw new \ReflectionException();
        }

        $reflectionPropertyType = $reflectionProperty->getType()->getName();
        if ('string' !== $reflectionPropertyType) {
            throw new \ReflectionException();
        }

        $reflectionProperty->setValue(
            $entity,
            // ManufacturerName VO has a __toString method
            $this->slugger->slugify($entity->name())
        );
    }
}
```

My question is: is my reasoning valid in your opinion? From a DDD perspective. What different approach would you incorporate so it fits the DDD concept of a project?